# Validate form in dialog Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have using material dialogs for Angular, where I need to enter title and select approve or reject variant.

Here code of the component

```
  import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from "@angular/material";
import {FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";
import { Payment } from '../payments/payment';


@Component({
    selector: 'editing-dialog',
    templateUrl: './editing-dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./editing-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class EditingDialogComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;
    reason:String;
    id: Number;
    statusdescription: String;

    constructor(
        fb: FormBuilder,
        private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditingDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data:Payment) {
            this.reason = data.Reason;
            this.id  = data.Id;
            this.statusdescription = data.StatusDescription;
            this.form = fb.group({
                reason: [this.reason, Validators.maxLength(5)],
                id: this.id,
                status: status
            });
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
    save() {
        this.dialogRef.close(this.form.value);
    }

    close() {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}
```

And here is html of this component

```
<h2>{{description}}</h2>

<mat-dialog-content [formGroup]="form">

    <mat-form-field>

        <input matInput required placeholder="Payment Reason" formControlName="reason" value="{{reason}}">


    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-radio-group formControlName="status">
        <mat-radio-button  value="Approved">Approved</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="Rejected">Rejected</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>

    <button class="mat-raised-button" (click)="save()">
        Ok
    </button>



    <button class="mat-raised-button"
            (click)="close()">
        Close
    </button>

</mat-dialog-actions>
```

I need to make validation if input is filled and if one of radio buttons selected when I click `ok` button. Now I have required validation for input.

How I can do this corretly?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when you create the form group, add required rule to fields you want to be required, for example here reason and status fields are required:

```
this.form = fb.group({
                    reason: [this.reason, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5)]],
                    id: this.id,
                    status: [status, [Validators.required]]
                });
```

then in save method:

```
save() {
    const {value, valid} = this.form;
    if(valid){
        this.dialogRef.close(value);
    }      
}
```

you may need to add mat-error element to show the validation errors in your html

Answer (score 2):

While you're building form

```
this.form = fb.group({
                reason: [this.reason, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5)]],
                id: this.id,
                status: status
            });
```

and when saving

```
    save() {
        if(this.form.valid) {
            this.dialogRef.close(this.form.value);
        }      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all confirm that if I had understood your question correctly or not. You have to click ok button and get the validation for your form.
If this is the problem then here is the solution:
Define your formgroup as in .ts:

```
this.form = fb.group({
                reason: [this.reason,  Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5)])],
                id: this.id,
                status: status
            });
```

Do define default value of status as I cannot see its definition in above code snippit.

Now call a function on click of ok button

```
clickOK(): void {
if (this.form.valid) {
    console.log('form is valid')
} else {
    console.log('form is invalid')
}
}
```

this.form.valid will return true if both formcontrol validations is true. If any one fails then it will return false.